# Concatenate column names in a new column based on their values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, concatenation, multiple-columns

| id | col1 | col2 | ones | twos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | col2 |  |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | col1 | col2 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | col2 |  |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | col1, col2 |  |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |  | col1,col2 |
| 6 | 0 | 1 | col2 |  |

I need to collect the column names containing the 1s and 2s into one column each.

Comment: Try reading when/otherwise or case from [here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-when-otherwise/) write a code and then we can try to resolve the error that you are getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`concat_ws` with a smart `when` condition may do it.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(1, 0, 1),
     (2, 1, 2),
     (3, 0, 1),
     (4, 1, 1),
     (5, 2, 2),
     (6, 0, 1)],
    ['id', 'col1', 'col2']
)
df = df.select(
    '*',
    F.concat_ws(', ', *[F.when(F.col(c) == 1, c) for c in {'col1', 'col2'}]).alias('ones'),
    F.concat_ws(', ', *[F.when(F.col(c) == 2, c) for c in {'col1', 'col2'}]).alias('twos'),
)
df.show()
# +---+----+----+----------+----------+
# | id|col1|col2|      ones|      twos|
# +---+----+----+----------+----------+
# |  1|   0|   1|      col2|          |
# |  2|   1|   2|      col1|      col2|
# |  3|   0|   1|      col2|          |
# |  4|   1|   1|col1, col2|          |
# |  5|   2|   2|          |col1, col2|
# |  6|   0|   1|      col2|          |
# +---+----+----+----------+----------+
```